# Why SharePoint 2013 search result sorting always put null values at last

Tags: search-results

I have a managed property called 'progamyear', which has values,for example, 2015, 2014, empty value etc. I am using getClientControl(this).sortOrRank in the display template. It works fine except for one thing: it always put the null value items at last no matter you perform 'ascending' or 'descending'. can anybody tell how to solve this issue? thanks.

Comment: Are you not wanting the nulls to show? Where do you want them? Maybe you could separate them into a different result set if sorting them with other records is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could either change the sorting applied like make the results sort based on your **programyear** property. You could also use  [Query rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj871676.aspx) to change the order in which results are displayed.

Comment: Could you please be more specific for your first approach? This is what I did, but I had above issue, Is this what you suggest? 
var availableSorts = ctx.DataProvider.get_availableSorts();
availableSorts.push({"name":"programyear_DEC","sorts":[{"p":"programyear","d":1}]});